# How does one convert a QuickTime duration in frames to a time format using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, quicktime, duration

I'm relatively new to AppleScript.  I'm trying to convert a QuickTime duration to a mm:ss time format that rounds to the nearest second.  Currently, it comes up as minutes and decimal places that I want to convert to seconds.

I much appreciate any suggestions.

Here's what I have, so far…

```
set these_items to choose file with prompt "Select source file(s)" with multiple selections allowed
repeat with oneItem in these_items
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            set q to QuickTime file (oneItem as text)
            set MovieDuration to ((duration of contents of q) / (time scale of contents of q)) / 60
            display dialog "Movie duration of " & name of q & " = " & MovieDuration
        end try
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out.  This seems to give me the result I want, anyway:

```
set these_items to choose file with prompt "Select source file(s)" with multiple selections allowed
repeat with oneItem in these_items
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            set q to QuickTime file (oneItem as text)
            set MovieSeconds to (((duration of contents of q) / (time scale of contents of q)) mod 60) as string
            set x to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in MovieSeconds) - 1) of MovieSeconds
            set MovieSeconds to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & x)
            set MovieMinutes to ((duration of contents of q) / (time scale of contents of q)) div 60
            display dialog "Movie duration of " & name of q & " = " & MovieMinutes & ":" & MovieSeconds
        end try
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the timestamp duration is to give the movie a date with a midnight time and then add the duration seconds to it, and then ask for the “time string” of that date. The time string is formatted HH:MM:SS.

This example works with QuickTime Player 10.3 on Mavericks:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    open (choose file with prompt "Choose a movie file:")
    set theMovie to a reference to the front document
    set theMovieDurationSeconds to the duration of theMovie
    set theMovieDate to date "Saturday, January 1, 2000 at 00:00:00"
    set theMovieDate to theMovieDate + theMovieDurationSeconds
    set theMovieDurationTimeString to the time string of theMovieDate
    display dialog "The movie duration:" & space & theMovieDurationTimeString buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK" with title (the name as text) with icon note giving up after 60
end tell
```

The time string will be “00:08:20” for a movie with a duration of 500 seconds.

The advantage of this method is you don’t have to do any math, and it should work with movies that are up to 23:59:59 in duration.

Also notice that you can just ask QuickTime Player for the movie duration.